# How to change OneToOne relationship using only Id

Tags: java, jpa

Suppose there is the following  entities :

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    int id;
    String name;
    ......
}

@Entity
class Bar {
    @Id
    int id;
    String name;
    @OneToOne
    Foo foo;
    ......
}
```

Is it possible to change Foo in Bar if entity is detached and I know only Id of existing Foo entity? I want something like this:

```
bar.getFoo.setId(/*Id of existing in database entity*/);
em.merge(bar);
```

And I don't want something like this:

```
Foo foo = em.find(Foo.class, /*Id of existing in database entity*/);
bar.setFoo(foo);
em.merge(bar);
```

Comment: which jpa implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using EclipseLink JPA 2.1

Comment: Not unless you mapped the foreign key in bar with a basic mapping, int for instance.  You could still have a foo reference, but you would have to make it readonly